# Android: Getting JSON from a uri

Tags: android, json

I have looked in all of the past stack overflow questions, and I just can't seem to figure this out.

What I am wanting to do is give a uri and receive a JSON from it. Here is my code so far:

```
public void setUpTheJSONs() throws IOException, JSONException, URISyntaxException {
    jsonSummonerInfo = getJsonSummonerInfo();
    jsonSummonerRankedStats = getJsonRankedStats();
}

public JSONObject getJsonSummonerInfo() throws IOException, JSONException, URISyntaxException {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/kinoscorpia?api_key=my_api_key_here");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if(entity != null){
        JSONObject temp =  new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        return temp;
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}

}
```

However, I never get a response and the response = httpClient.execute(httpPost) line.

When you type the uri into a website, the JSON pops up, but not when the code runs.

Any help?

Thanks ☺

Comment: Where is your `getJsonSummonerInfo()` method executed? If it's in the body of an `Activity` or `Service` you may be getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Check logcat for an exceptions.

Comment: Do you have the INTERNET permission in your manifest?

Comment: I would recommend you NOT to post your api_key

Comment: When you type the uri in a browser, you use `HTTP GET` method, in the code you post you use `HTTP POST`, check if your server deals with POST correctly. Plus, I would recommend you use [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) library for transmitting network data.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're meaning to do a POST request? Your code doesn't seem to actually send anything to the server short of the url where in a POST request you would generally attach something to the requests entity.

Try sending it as a GET request and see if that solves your problem:

```
public JSONObject getJsonSummonerInfo() throws IOException, JSONException, URISyntaxException 
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/kinoscorpia?api_key=my_api_key_here");

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if(entity != null)
    {
        JSONObject temp =  new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        return temp;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree, you need to use HttpGet, all services from this API are GET

Answer (score 0):

With [DroidParts](https://github.com/yanchenko/droidparts):

```
public JSONObject getJsonSummonerInfo(Context ctx) throws HTTPException {
    return new RESTClient2(ctx).getJSONObject("https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/30170613/ranked?season=SEASON2015&api_key=(**MYAPIKEY**)");
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking for alternative ways of doing things - I think he probably wants to know why his existing code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Code itself has no problems.
Perhaps the link is broken.
Check if the link throws http error or check code by this URI
`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=stackoverflow`

Comment: I updated the code. I'm just not getting a JSON from it. However, when I put the uri in a webpage, the JSON pops up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Print out `entity`and `response` to a console and check it, httpget might be the problem